# how to change folder permission 777 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am particularly new in CodeIgniter. I have a task that require me to upload multiple files into the server. Of all recents searches made, I found that all of them require me to change upload folder permission into 777. The question is how to change them?

Comment: local or live? ubuntu or windows ?

Comment: changing the permission has no relation to any framework. It's specific to OS that you are using.

Comment: **Never ever** change the folder permission to 777. There must be a more sensible value

Comment: if you want to do this in ubuntu you can simply run `sudo chmod 777 ./folder -R`

Comment: As mentioned before, be very careful with 777 permissions. When you want to change folder permissions on a Linux system, you may call `system("chmod 777 ./folder -R");` in your PHP code but that would require the web server user to be allowed to change permissions on the parent folder. On Windows `chmod` is not available so you'd need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the directory and set the permission like that

```
mkdir("test", 0777);
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the permission of any dir/folder has no relation to any framework. It's specific to OS that you are using.

If Ubuntu in recursive

```
chmod -R 0777 folder_name/
```

without recursive

```
chmod 0777 folder_name/
```

For windows
Refer: https://superuser.com/questions/929023/chmod-777-in-windows-7

Comment: what if the OP is using CentOS or debian?